# How to add Polygon (Matic) to MetaMask?

Tags: metamask, polygon, mainnet

Metamask has mainnet installed, while testnets are hidden by default. But what details are required when adding a custom network to connect to the Polygon (Matic) network via Metamask? Are there any security risks, or trojan horse (fake) connection details to watch out for?

And in general, how will surfing the Polygon network be different than Ethereum Mainnet? Are there no noticeable differences in UI/UX?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Polygon provider such as : https://polygon-rpc.com/

Just click on `Add Network` in the network selector at the top of Metamask and input the following information for Polygon mainnet :

- Network Name : Polygon
- New RPC URL : https://polygon-rpc.com/
- Chain ID : 137
- Currency Symbol : MATIC
- Block explorer : https://polygonscan.com/

Feel free to change the provider and / or the block explorer for your favorite one.

Comment: why are there so many alternatives to RPC URL and block explorer, and how are they not equivalent?

Comment: Well technically every full node could serve as an RPC endpoint so it can get a bit confusing.. It's a decentralized system so you won't have a single RPC endpoint for everyone that would defeat the whole purpose. The same principle applies to block explorer to some extent. It's just that both are services that any node can provide quite easily.  It's a good thing to have many alternatives, it's just reassuring regarding the overall accessibility to the system.